# Symfony set data to multiple choiceType

Tags: php, symfony, multiple-choice

I set symfony choiceType value from inside the controller by using this:

```
    $editForm->get('userJobTitle')->setData($job->getJobTitle()->getId());
```

How to do it for multiple choiceType? the following method isn't working

```
 $editForm->get('userskills')->setData($job->getSkills());
```

where `getSkills` function return Doctrine collection.

Comment: The `ChoiceType` expects a `array`, so `$job->getSkills()->toArray()` should work?

Comment: thank you @yceruto i try it but it doesn't work

Comment: I can't figure out what exactly you want... you want to save multiple selected choices from a dropdown into db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setData()` method requires array of strings which contain the values of selected options so i do:

```
$usSkills = $job->getSkills()->getValues();
        $vals = array();
        foreach ($usSkills as $us){
            $vals[] = (string)$us->getId();
        }
        $editForm->get('userskills')->setData($vals);
```

and that solved the problem