# ChoiceType Data with multiple values needs array but gives "Array to string conversion". How to solve?

Tags: php, symfony

While using Symfony 4.3 FormBuilderInterface, I'm building a form. It's important that I don't use coded classes with data structure in it.

I have a ChoiceType with multiple values that is in need of some help while filling.

Building the form is fine. Even returning (multiple) values from the form works perfectly. However, when I try to pre-fill the form with setData... It responds a bit schizofrenic.

Behold

Given:

```
$arr = ['Person1' => 'John', 'Person123' => 'George'];
$form->add('RelatedToPerson', ChoiceType::class, [ 'multiple' => true, 'choices' => $arr]);
```

Now we want to set the data for this multiple choice with:

```
$chosen = ['Person123'];
```

So I do:

```
$form->get('RelatedToPerson')->setData($chosen);
```

Which gives: "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Why? It's an array of strings. It doesn't tell what it needs.
Maybe it needs a comma separated string?

I do:

```
$form->get($item['name'])->setData(implode(', ', $chosen));
```

And get:
"Unable to transform value for property path "[RelatedToPerson]": Expected an array."

Conclusion: It does need an array, but when I'm giving it one... it's not the right type?

What must I do to solve this problem?

Comment: can you show us the annotations for the property? you did multiple true, so It's normal to have an array as result

Comment: The annotations for what property? As said, there are only arrays, no classes. The createFormBuilder is called with an array as well ($resultArray), not with a class.
The result comes back perfectly into the $resultArray as well and can be handled. Parsing that result (the selection for RelatedToPerson in this example) back into a new form however is where I get stuck...

Answer (score 0):

The method setData sets the default value of the form element, and expects a string. For your example, you should use:

```
$form->get('RelatedToPerson')->setData('George');
```

to have the second option of your choices array to be selected on form display.

Comment: For single value fields, your answer sets the value, overriding every other value that was there. For multiple value fields, it expects an array. Thus, your statement yields the second error I've given "Unable to transform..."

I suspect that I might need a "Data Transformator"? How to use one without a class?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! 
Apparently, the 'array of strings' I gave to the setData was contaminated somehow. You really need to make sure all the values in your array are explicitly defined as (string). If not, you will get an error message.

One solution is described here: [Symfony set data to multiple choiceType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376155/symfony-set-data-to-multiple-choicetype)

For my solution I did something similar: I went to the source (where the data first enters the application) and made sure to put a (string) before every addition to the array. 
The data that I collect is originally a string, but apparently for some of the strings, php gives it another type. :-/